# What does style.display = '' actually do?

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

After researching this issue for a couple of hours, I found that one of the most efficient ways to toggle a page element's display (in HTML) is to do something like:

```
// showing
document.getElementById('element').style.display = '';

// hiding
document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'none';
```

**Simple question:** What does `style.display = ''` actually do?

Does it "reset" the original display property?

Or does it remove the display property, thereby using the default style for display?

..........................................

**Would be nice to know:** Does anyone know of any links to any kind of documentation about this?

(Yes, I have Google-d this issue, but I'm probably not entering the right search term and keep coming up with completely un-related search results.)

Thanks for any suggestions or links.

Comment: I explained it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556994/css-display-auto/6557005#6557005), if it helps.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it resets the element's display property to the default by blanking out the inline "display: none", causing the element to fall back on its display property as defined by the page's ranking CSS rules.

For example, here's a `<div>` with the ID of "myElement".

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

A `<div>` has a setting of `display:block` by default. In our style sheet, suppose we specify that your `<div>` is to be displayed as `table`:

```
div#myElement
{
    display:table;
}
```

Upon loading your page, the `<div>` is displayed as `table`. If you want to hide this `<div>` with scripting, you might do any of these:

```
// JavaScript:
document.getElementById("myElement").style.display = 'none';

// jQuery:
$("#myElement").toggle(); // if currently visible
$("#myElement").hide();
$("#myElement").css({"display":"none"});
```

All of thse have the same effect: adding an inline `style` property to your `<div>`:

```
<div id="myElement" style="display:none"></div>
```

If you wish to show the element again, any of these would work:

```
// JavaScript:
document.getElementById("myElement").style.display = "";

// jQuery:
$("#myElement").toggle(); // if currently hidden
$("#myElement").show();
$("#myElement").css({"display":""});
```

These remove the `display` CSS property from the inline `style` property:

```
<div style=""></div>
```

Since the inline style no longer specifies a `display`, the `<div>` goes back to being displayed as `table`, since that's what we put in the style sheet. The `<div>` does **not** revert to being displayed as `block` because our CSS overrode that default setting; blanking out the inline `display` property does not negate the rules in our style sheets.

---

For giggles, here's the Google query I used for verification of my answer: `javascript style display empty string default`

...and a couple of links where this is mentioned:

http://jszen.blogspot.com/2004/07/table-rowsrevealed.html

http://www.harrymaugans.com/2007/03/05/how-to-create-a-collapsible-div-with-javascript-and-css/ 
(not in the article, but in the comments section)

Comment: Jake, thank you very much for the explanation and the links. I truly appreciate that a great deal. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

It sets the `display` style to the default value for that element. For most elements if not all, the default value is something other than `none`.

Answer (score 6):

It removes the value for the display property so that the default value is used.

It *does not* reset the original display property.

If you for example have this:

```
<span id="test" style="display:block;">b</span>
```

And do this:

```
document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById('test').style.display = '';
```

the `display` style used for the element ends up being `inline` because that's the default for the element, it is not reset back to the style specified in the HTML code.

Comment: When you say "the default value", does that include applicable styles in a stylesheet? If there is a stylesheet that says `#test { display: block; }` (or perhaps `span { display: block; }`) then that would apply wouldn't it?

Comment: @nnnnnn: That is correct. Also inherited styles apply, it's only the inline style that is affected by the `style` property.

Comment: Thank you, Guffa, for the explanation and the code samples. You rock!

Comment: So my understanding is that if I declare a DIV as FLEX in a css file, then hide it using display:none in JavaScript , I can't use display:"" to show it again, because that would set the DIV to BLOCK (the default for the element) instead of the desired FLEX. Fooey. If I want to hide and show DIVs efficiently (like to simulate tabs), I still have to save the original display style somewhere, or else use documentfragment DOM manipulation (but I can't find a tutorial on how to do that).

Answer (score 1):

It sets the css for that element's display to `null`  which essentially wipes out what was set and it reverts to its default value.