# I want to make an element display when a button is pressed. by default the element is shown, how do I make it display none by default?

Tags: javascript, css, button, hide

All the stuff for the button seems right and it works in reverse of what I want currently. when I load the page the div: myDIV is there and the button toggles it disappearing and reappearing. How do I make myDIV none by default but still have the button function as a toggle

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add style `display:none` to div  chartContainer

Comment: I have already tried that and it just means that I have to click the button twice for the div to appear :)

Comment: where is button toggles it disappearing and reappearing?

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: so, you made `<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">` and your code didn't work? perhaps you should show the *real* code, as adding the style as per first comment would work (I notice you've since changed the code in the question to make the first comment look absurd, however, the comment is 100% correct)

Comment: even when I have this simplified version I have the problem of having to click the button twice to display myDIV initially [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gquxwodj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point is in here [style.display = '' actually do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420109/what-does-style-display-actually-do)

When you use `style.display` to get display status, it can not get display attribute defined in css

Answer (score 0):

You need to get CSS Value first to toggle the display value with a button in JS. By default, it is advised not to give inline style on HTML.

```js
function myFunction() {
 const cont = document.querySelector("#chartContainer");
 const styles = getComputedStyle(cont)
  const displayStyle = styles.display;
  if(displayStyle === "none"){
   cont.style.display = "block";
  }else {
   cont.style.display = "none";
  }
  
}

const BTN = document.querySelector("button");
BTN.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#chartContainer {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  float: below;
  display: none;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div id="chartContainer">
    </div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"> </script>
</div>
```