# Hide all, show a class with css

Tags: html, css, printing

Context: making printable invoices to generate in a browser.

It's common in making printable webpages to use an `@media print` rule to change the way the content looks for a printed page. Ideally, because I'm printing only a small part of the page, I'd like to hide everything and then display the contents of a particular element.

Structure is something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="topMenu">...lots of elements...</div>
    <div id="sideMenu">...lots more...</div>
    <div class="tools">...some tools...</div>
    <div class="printing">...some elements I want to print...</div>
    <div class="tools">...more stuff I don't want to print...</div>
</body>
```

### Stuff I've tried:

Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
body * {
    display: none;
}
.printing, .printing * { /* Both parts are needed to make it display */
    display: block !important;
}
```

But this won't work because some elements need to be inline and some need to be block. I've played with some different values for `display` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and can't find one that easily resets the value to its original. `display: initial` seems to be treated like `inline`.

The suggestion in [CSS: "display: auto;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556994/css-display-auto) seems to only work for JS.

Of course, it is possible to explicity "hide" the stuff I don't want printed rather than display the stuff I do want, but it seems to me that it should be possible to go the other way.

In this question [How to only show certain parts with CSS for Print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463796/how-to-only-show-certain-parts-with-css-for-print) suggests `body *:not(.printable *) {display:none;}` but notes (as backed up [on the w3 negation page](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#negation) ) that this is not yet supported.

I note that the [w3 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#propdef-display) and [the display-outside page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#propdef-display-outside) seem to recommend using an unknown (to webkit) `box-suppress` property to preserve the display value while not displaying the element.

### My questions:

What is the best way to hide everything and target certain elements for display when they don't all share a common display property?

What exactly does `box-suppress` do?

Comment: have you try with **less**

Comment: To answer your auxiliary question, `box-suppress` is a possible future replacement for `display:none` that will hopefully make it easier to hide elements without worrying about changing its display type. I don't think it's currently supported so I'd stay away from it for now. More: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/

Comment: Thank you @Ben Leggiero. It appears to me based on reading the docs on `box-suppress` that this will make it possible to "toggle" display in the future rather than resetting it, which was my original approach, rather than building a specific selector. Will that be (a/the) use case for `box-suppress`?

Comment: @Josiah it appears that's exactly the case!

Comment: @BenLeggiero - imho, you should edit your answer to include that so people looking for future box-suppress information can find how to use it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Josiah great point! I've added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you specifically tagged this CSS3, try using CSS3!

```
body>:not(.printing) {
    display: none;
}
```

This should work for the example you gave. I hope it works for your real-world application!

---

To answer your auxiliary question, as of October 2014, `box-suppress` is a possible future replacement for `display:none` that will hopefully make it easier to both hide and remove elements from the flow without worrying about changing its display type (as opposed to `visibility` still keeps it in the flow, and `position:absolute` which still keeps it visible). I don't think it's currently supported so I'd stay away from it for now. If you want to know more, see http://w3.org/TR/css-display

Comment: Excellent - I hadn't thought of using the > selector. This works perfectly!

Comment: @Josiah glad I could help! :3

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `display` for this purpose.  See [Display HTML child element when parent element is display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956937/display-html-child-element-when-parent-element-is-displaynone)

However, you *can* use `visibility`, as long as you use absolute positioning for the hidden content:

```
body, body * {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.printing, .printing * {
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any absolute or fixed elements, you can use an alternative way of hiding elements.

Instead of using `display: none` to hide your elements, try using:

```
body * {
    position:absolute;
    top: -999999px;
    left: -999999px;
}
```

To set it back use:

```
.printing, .printing * {
     position: initial;
     /* OR */
     position: static;
}
```

Comment: That could work. I have some absolutely positioned elements but I can probably rework that.