# Why doesn't this code display the button after I hide it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I run this JavaScript code, `button2` doesn't get displayed again. I'm not sure why this is happening. I am trying to use this in a game I am creating. I searched this up on Google multiple times and couldn't find an answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .btn1 {
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
            }
            .btn2 {
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn1" onclick="showBtn2()">
            Show Button 2
        </button>
        <button class="btn2" id="btn2"></button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

        function showBtn2() {
            btn2.style.display = "auto";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `auto` display is CSS. As tarkh mentioned in his answer, display `block` would insert the new button below the initial button, and other display options would have other behaviors. But the `display` property does not have a value `auto`.

This may be my opinion, but I think modern websites shouldn't use the `onclick` function for events. We should separate our HTML, JS and CSS. This helps with reusability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

So I would create a solution that uses an event handler in the Javascript. Something like:

```
window.onload = function(){
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
const btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn1");

    for(let i = 0; i < btn1.length; i++) {
        btn1[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            btn2.style.display = "block";   
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to handle this and provide more reusable code is to use `<element>.classList.remove()` and `<element>.classList.add()` to set or unset a `hidden` class. This can also be useful for toggling with `<element>.classList.toggle()`.

This has the added advantage of being able to set your default display style in the CSS rather than burying it in the javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .btn1 {
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
            }
            .btn2 {
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
                /* allows setting preferred display in CSS */
                display: block; 
            }
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn1" onclick="showBtn2()">
            Show Button 2
        </button>
        <button class="btn1" onclick="toggleBtn2()">
            Toggle Button 2
        </button>
        <button class="btn2 hidden" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

        function showBtn2() {
            btn2.classList.remove("hidden");
        }
        function toggleBtn2() {
            btn2.classList.toggle("hidden");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `btn2.style.display = "block";`?
Or, as @charlietfl added, `btn2.style.display = "inline";` since that is what browser default is for a button

> display: block means that the element is displayed as a block, as
> paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace
> above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except
> when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another
> element, for instance).
>
> display: inline means that the element is displayed inline, inside the
> current block on the same line. Only when it's between two blocks does
> the element form an 'anonymous block', that however has the smallest
> possible width.

```css
.btn1 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
.btn2 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn1" onclick="showBtn2()">
            Show Button 2
        </button>
        <button class="btn2" id="btn2">new button here</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

        function showBtn2() {
            btn2.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Or 'inline' since that is what browser default is for a button

Comment: or `unset` to revert it to default

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .btn1 {
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
            }
            .btn2 {
                background-color: white;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 12px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn1" onclick="showBtn2()">
            Show Button 2
        </button>
        <button class="btn2" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
        function showBtn2() {
            btn2.style.display = "inline";
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Use `display = inline or block` instead of `auto`.

Add some text content to button 2 like this:
`<button class="btn2" id="btn2">Button 2</button>`

Answer (score 0):

[CSS: "display: auto;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556994/css-display-auto)

display does not have an auto attribute.
you can try "inline" or "block".

```
'''
function showBtn2() {
    btn2.style.display = "inline";
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
btn2.style.display = "block";
```

for your script because css display doesn't have that kind of attribute you

you can read it more here : [more](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
you'll see there's no such thing as **display:auto**

Comment: This displays the button, but not in the right position.